# sort by using radio button is not working django

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a web page as shown below, so when I click on any 1 of my radio button, my url will show what I have click but, my data table won't sort in ascending order according to what I have selected, how do I fix this issue and how do I make it so that when I use the search bar and filter the page, it will still be sort in ascending order?

[image]

views.py

```
@login_required()
def ViewMCO(request):
    search_post = request.GET.get('q')
    if (search_post is not None) and search_post:
        allusername = Photo.objects.filter(Q(reception__icontains=search_post) | Q(partno__icontains=search_post) | Q(
            Customername__icontains=search_post) | Q(mcoNum__icontains=search_post) | Q(status__icontains=search_post)
                                           | Q(serialno__icontains=search_post))
        if not allusername:
            allusername = Photo.objects.all().order_by("-Datetime")


    else:
        allusername = Photo.objects.all().order_by("-Datetime") # The newest submitted log data will appear at the top



    page = request.GET.get('page')
    paginator = Paginator(allusername, 6)
    try:
        allusername = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        allusername = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        allusername = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)




    context = {'allusername': allusername, 'query': search_post}
    return render(request, 'ViewMCO.html', context)
```

ViewMCO.html

```
    {% extends "customerbase.html" %}
    {% block content %}
    <style>
    table {
        border-collapse:separate;
        border:solid black 1px;
        border-radius:6px;
        -moz-border-radius:6px;
    }
    
    td, th {
        border-left:solid black 1px;
        border-top:solid black 1px;
    }
    
    th {
        border-top: none;
    }
    
    td:first-child, th:first-child {
         border-left: none;
    }

    .pagination a {
    padding: 10px;
    }

    .sort {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
    }


    </style>
    <script>
      
    
     // Function to download table data into csv file
            function download_table_as_csv(table_id, separator = ',') {
                var rows = document.querySelectorAll('table#' + table_id + ' tr');
                var csv = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll('td, th');
                    for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
                        var data = cols[j].innerText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '').replace(/(\s\s)/gm, ' ')
                        data = data.replace(/"/g, '""');
                        row.push('"' + data + '"');
                    }
                    csv.push(row.join(separator));
                }
                var csv_string = csv.join('\n');
                var filename = 'export_' + table_id + '_' + new Date().toLocaleDateString() + '.csv';
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.style.display = 'none';
                link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                link.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv_string));
                link.setAttribute('download', filename);
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            };

    </script>


       <div style="padding-left:16px">
         <br>
    
    
     <div class="form-block">
         <h6>Search for Part Number/ Serial Number/ Reception Number/ MCO Number/ Customer Name/ Status</h6>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{% url 'ViewMCO' %}" method='GET' value='{{ request.GET.q }}'>
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="q" value='{{ request.GET.q }}'/>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>

         <div class="sort">
           <h5 class="col-md-3">Sort By : </h5>


                <div id="sortBlock" class="col-md-9">
                    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{% url 'ViewMCO' %}" method='GET' value='{{ request.GET.p }}'>
                    <div class="sort">
                        <input type="radio" id="partno" name="sortType" value="partno">
                        <label for="partno">Part Number</label>
                    </div>

                     <div class="sort">
                        <input type="radio" id="serialno" name="sortType" value="serialno">
                        <label for="serialno">Serial Number</label>
                    </div>

                     <div class="sort">
                        <input type="radio" id="receptionno" name="sortType" value="receptionno">
                        <label for="receptionno">Reception Number</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="sort">
                        <input type="radio" id="mcoNum" name="sortType" value="mcoNum">
                        <label for="mcoNum">MCO Number</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="sort">
                        <input type="radio" id="Customername" name="sortType" value="Customername">
                        <label for="Customername">Customer Name</label>
                    </div>
                         <div class="sort">
                        <input type="Submit" value="Sort"/>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
         </div>
     </div>





       <table id="viewTable" class="m-2">
            <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <a href="#" onclick="download_table_as_csv('viewTable');">Download as CSV</a>
           <br>
    
      <tr class="header">
        <th>Latest Log</th>
          <th>Part Number</th>
          <th>Serial Number</th>
          <th>Reception Number</th>
          <th>MCO Number</th>
          <th>Customer Name</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
           {% for photo in allusername %}
    
    
      <tr>
            <td>{{photo.Datetime}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.partno}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.serialno}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.reception}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.mcoNum}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.Customername}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.status}}</td>


          <td>
          <form action="{% url 'customerdetails' photo.id %}" method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">View</button>
          </form>
          </td>
      </tr>
    
    {% endfor %}
    
    </table>
         <br>

  {% if allusername.has_other_pages %}

  <ul class="pagination pr-3 mr-1 ml-auto">

    {% if allusername.has_previous %}
      <li><a href="?q={{ query|urlencode }}&page={{ allusername.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% for i in allusername.paginator.page_range %}
      {% if allusername.number == i %}
        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
      {% else %}
        <li><a href="?q={{ query|urlencode }}&page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% if allusername.has_next %}
      <li><a href="?q={{ query|urlencode }}&page={{ allusername.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
    {% endif %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}


    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the queryset data, it needs to be implemented like below. If you want to add descending or ascending sort_by, then you can make it with passing order_by parameter with '-' as descending, empty string as ascending, for example '-id' as descending, 'id' as ascending.

```
@login_required()
def ViewMCO(request):
    search_post = request.GET.get('q')
    if (search_post is not None) and search_post:
        allusername = Photo.objects.filter(Q(reception__icontains=search_post) | Q(partno__icontains=search_post) | Q(
            Customername__icontains=search_post) | Q(mcoNum__icontains=search_post) | Q(status__icontains=search_post)
                                           | Q(serialno__icontains=search_post))
        if not allusername:
            allusername = Photo.objects.all().order_by("-Datetime")


    else:
        allusername = Photo.objects.all().order_by("-Datetime") # The newest submitted log data will appear at the top

    # example code starts

    sort_type = request.GET.get('sortType')
    allusername = allusername.order_by(sort_type)

    # example code ends

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    paginator = Paginator(allusername, 6)
    try:
        allusername = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        allusername = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        allusername = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)




    context = {'allusername': allusername, 'query': search_post}
    return render(request, 'ViewMCO.html', context)
```